# Chrome CSS absolute position glitch

Tags: css, google-chrome, html-table, position, absolute

I want to make a gallery generated by php where every image is grayscale and becomes coloured only when the mouse goes over it. For various reasons I didn't want to use CSS image backgrounds so I went with absolute positioned images instead. When the cursor hovers over a table's td element the absolute positioned image pops over the gray image. Since no coordinates length or width is defined the rgb image should be right on top of the gray one. In Firefox that's exactly what happens but in Chrome the first and second images in every row are shifted to the left. The last third picture works fine.

```
#main #album {
    width:100%; /* 600px */
}
#main #album  td{
    padding-bottom:20px;
    text-align:center;
}
#main #album  td img:first-child{   
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}
#main #album  td:hover img:first-child{
    display:inline;
}
<table id="album">
<tr>
<td><img src="/img/mini/dezsma01.jpg" /><img src="/img/mini/gray/dezsma01.jpg" /><br />A
<td><img src="/img/mini/dezsma01.jpg" /><img src="/img/mini/gray/dezsma01.jpg" /><br />B
<td><img src="/img/mini/dezsma01.jpg" /><img src="/img/mini/gray/dezsma01.jpg" /><br />C
</table>
```

**UPDATE**

The CSS reset suggested by diggersworld solved the problem, but I have also tried to use lists and that worked too. Here is the code:

```
#main #albumlist {
    width:100%; 
    list-style-type:none;
}
#main #albumlist a {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:180px;
    height:auto;
    padding-left:20px;  
    padding-bottom:20px;
    text-align:center;
}
#main #albumlist li a:first-child{
    padding-left:0;
}
#main #albumlist a img:first-child {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}
#main #albumlist a:hover img:first-child {  
    display:inline;
}

<ul id="albumlist"><li>
        <a href="/img/big/dezsma01.jpg"><img src="/img/mini/dezsma01.jpg" /><img src="/img/mini/gray/dezsma01.jpg" /><br />A</a>
        <a href="/img/big/dezsma01.jpg"><img src="/img/mini/dezsma01.jpg" /><img src="/img/mini/gray/dezsma01.jpg" /><br />B</a>
        <a href="/img/big/dezsma01.jpg"><img src="/img/mini/dezsma01.jpg" /><img src="/img/mini/gray/dezsma01.jpg" /><br />C</a>
</li></ul>
```

Comment: Quick Tip: Using a list would be a more semantic approach to listing images in your album. Tables should only really be used for tabular data.

Comment: We used to have these things back in the late 90's called *mouseovers* or *rollovers* that used JavaScript to replace one image with another when you moused over it.  Right now, you have redundant content that doesn't make any sense if the styling is removed.  Using the JS style mouseover is a lot more appropriate than embedding 2 images this way.

Comment: diggersworld this is only the first row of the 3x3 table I display. cimmanon That wouldn't solve the problem lunless I directly change the src value. Which is of course alright even though this way I don't need to preload images with javascript and I don't need to do any DOM manipulation at all.

Comment: @nekdolan that doesn't really make a difference.

Comment: @diggersworld okay I will try and see if it behaves differently. I'm not very comfortable with horizontal lists.. maybe I don't really need go horizontal at all...

Answer (score 0):

The difference in behaviour could be down to a number of things. Usually the main issue is the difference between browser default styles, as they all have a set of defined presets. These presets can be overridden easily by using a reset stylesheet. This basically resets all CSS attributes to a base starting point and provides a level foundation to build upon for all browsers.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

I mentioned in the comment that using a table isn't the ideal solution. Tables used to be used commonly in the 90s for layout. However CSS has become more useful since then and allows developers to achieve a lot more with less HTML.

You should most definitely master the art of using lists. They tend to be one of the elements I use the most when developing websites. You'll be surprised how many things are actually lists when you break them down semantically. They're also a lot more flexible than tables and you will see a massive benefit if you ever delve into responsive web design.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Also tried lists (see first post) and that works without any reset. If I remember correctly absolute positioned elements - if coordinates are not set - should be positioned exactly the same place as they would be positioned if the element was not removed form the flow. So this is a bug even if a reset solves it.